# Error storing an image on device public external storage

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-manifest

I'm trying to store an image in the external storage directory of the device (an image captured with a camera). I've followed this: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.

But there is a problem when tapping the button for taking the picture.

Here it's the output of the logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
...
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.finalproject/files/Pictures/JPEG_20201229_115929_7049104839298740054.jpg
...
```

Here it's my dispatch picture function:

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent (View view) {
       Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File imageFile=null;
            imageFile=createImageFile();

            if (imageFile!=null){
                pathToFile= imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.example.finalproject.fileprovider",imageFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here it's my android manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finalproject">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FinalProject"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.finalproject.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Activity_main:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:onClick="dispatchTakePictureIntent"

        android:text="camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.995" />
```

And finally, the file paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.finalproject/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

The imageFile.getAbsolutePath() is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.finalproject/files/Pictures/JPEG_20201230_095104_22370060963499233.jpg

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time so I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

P.D: if more information or code is needed, please comment and I would upload it.

Comment: Hello! Could you please add, xml file when "android:onClick" is executed and the java/kotlin file when it is invoked? Also, are you using androidX?

Comment: @rguzman I've just uploaded the where android: onclick is executed. The function dispatchTakePictureIntent (the code is above). I don't actually know if i'm using androidX, how can I see it?

Comment: Please tell the value of `imageFile.getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: `path="Android/data/com.example.finalproject/files/Pictures"` Change to `path="."`

Comment: @blackapps, i've done that and now it works correctly, there are not any error messages. But, it doesn't store the image.

Comment: The imageFile.getAbsolutePath() is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.finalproject/files/Pictures/JPEG_20201230_095104_22370060963499233.jpg

Comment: `But, it doesn't store the image. –`. It? Come to the point please.